# C# namespace alias - what's the point?

Tags: c#, namespaces

Where or when would one would use namespace aliasing like

```
 using someOtherName =  System.Timers.Timer;
```

It seems to me that it would just add more confusion to understanding the language.

Comment: How about a system wide `using int = System.Int32` in C#? Useful, isn't it? Its the same use that can be taken advantage of elsewhere.

Comment: @nawfal I believe type aliases are not exportable. Meaning you cannot define something like `using int = System.Int32`, and use it in places other than the declaring file. So this `int` to `Int32` alias may either be achieved by some other means, or is a special thing in the compiler/runtime.

Comment: @KFL that's true, but the benefit both provide is of the same nature.

Comment: @nawfal your argument about `using int = System.Int32` is both wrong and misleading - it's wrong because `int` alias is not implemented the way you described. It's misleading because you imply type aliases can be used globally, just as how `int` is used over `Int32`.

Comment: @KFL i didnt imply both. I just stated why having a custom name for a type could be useful.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

That is a type alias, not a namespace alias; it is useful to disambiguate - for example, against:

```
using WinformTimer = System.Windows.Forms.Timer;
using ThreadingTimer = System.Threading.Timer;
```

(ps: thanks for the choice of `Timer` ;-p)

Otherwise, if you use both `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` and `System.Threading.Timer` in the same file, then you'd have to keep giving the full names (since `Timer` could be confusing).

It also plays a part with `extern` aliases for using types with the same fully-qualified type name from different assemblies - rare, but useful to be supported.

---

Actually, I can see another use: when you want quick access to a type but don't want to use a regular `using` because you can't import some conflicting extension methods. A bit convoluted but here's an example:

```
namespace RealCode {
    //using Foo; // can't use this - it breaks DoSomething
    using Handy = Foo.Handy;
    using Bar;
    static class Program {
        static void Main() {
            Handy h = new Handy(); // prove available
            string test = "abc";            
            test.DoSomething(); // prove available
        }
    }
}
namespace Foo {
    static class TypeOne {
        public static void DoSomething(this string value) { }
    }
    class Handy {}
}
namespace Bar {
    static class TypeTwo {
        public static void DoSomething(this string value) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: It can be used to alias either namespaces or type names.

Comment: @Sean: yes, but the example given was to a type

Comment: @lupefiasco: convenient of the OP to choose `System.Timers.Timer` ;-p

Comment: Ah, thought you were referring to the concept and not the specific example.  Mea culpa.

Answer (score 29):

I use it when I've got multiple namespaces with conflicting sub namespaces and/or object names you could just do something like [as an example]:

```
using src = Namespace1.Subspace.DataAccessObjects;
using dst = Namespace2.Subspace.DataAccessObjects;

...

src.DataObject source = new src.DataObject();
dst.DataObject destination = new dst.DataObject();
```

Which would otherwise have to be written:

```
Namespace1.Subspace.DataAccessObjects.DataObject source = 
  new Namespace1.Subspace.DataAccessObjects.DataObject();

Namespace2.Subspace.DataAccessObjects.DataObject dstination = 
  new Namespace2.Subspace.DataAccessObjects.DataObject();
```

It saves a ton of typing and can be used to make code a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 20):

In addition to the examples mentioned, type aliases (rather than namespace aliases) can be handy when repeatedly referring to generic types:

```
Dictionary<string, SomeClassWithALongName> foo = new Dictionary<string, SomeClassWithALongName>();

private void DoStuff(Dictionary<string, SomeClassWithALongName> dict) {}
```

Versus:

```
using FooDict = Dictionary<string, SomeClassWithALongName>;

FooDict foo = new FooDict();

private void DoStuff(FooDict dict) {}
```

Answer (score 9):

Brevity.

There are fringe benefits to provide clarity between namespaces which share type names, but essentially it's just sugar.

Comment: It clearly shows which symbol you are using. It is not just sugar, but a little bit verbose (if you don't want to define a new name).

Answer (score 7):

I always use it in situations like this

```
using Utility = MyBaseNamespace.MySubNamsepace.Utility;
```

where `Utility` would otherwise have a different context (like `MyBaseNamespace.MySubNamespace.MySubSubNamespace.Utility`), but I expect/prefer `Utility` to always point to that one particular class.

Answer (score 6):

It is very useful when you have multiple classes with the same name in multiple included namespaces.  For example...

```
namespace Something.From.SomeCompanyA {
    public class Foo {
        /* ... */
    }
}

namespace CompanyB.Makes.ThisOne {
    public class Foo {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

You can use aliases to make the compiler happy and to make things more clear for you and others on your team:

```
using CompanyA = Something.From.CompanyA;
using CompanyB = CompanyB.Makes.ThisOne;

/* ... */

CompanyA.Foo f = new CompanyA.Foo();
CompanyB.Foo x = new CompanyB.Foo();
```

Answer (score 3):

We have defined namespace aliases for all of our namespaces. This makes it very easy to see where a class comes from, e.g:

```
using System.Web.WebControls;
// lots of other using statements

// contains the domain model for project X
using dom = Company.ProjectX.DomainModel; 
// contains common web functionality
using web = Company.Web;
// etc.
```

and

```
// User from the domain model
dom.User user = new dom.User(); 
// Data transfer object
dto.User user = new dto.User(); 
// a global helper class
utl.SomeHelper.StaticMethod(); 
// a hyperlink with custom functionality
// (as opposed to System.Web.Controls.HyperLink)
web.HyperLink link = new web.HyperLink();
```

We have defined some guidelines how the aliases must be named and everyone is using them.

Comment: Don't you find that often the alias has more to do with the context in which it is being used than the physical location of the object?

Answer (score 3):

I find the aliases very useful in unit testing. When you are writing unit tests, it is a common practice to declare the subject to test as

```
MyClass myClassUT;
```

being `myClassUT` the subject **U**nder **T**est. But what if you want to write unit tests for a static class with static methods? Then you can create an alias like this:

```
using MyStaticClassUT = Namespace.MyStaticClass;
```

Then you can write your unit tests like this:

```
public void Test()
{
    var actual = MyStaticClassUT.Method();
    var expected = ...
}
```

and you never loose sight of what the subject under test is.

Answer (score 3):

In one way it is really handy while coding in Visual Studio.

**Use-case**: Let's say I've to use only few classes e.g. `SqlConnection` from a namespace `System.Data`. In normal course I'll import the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace at the top of the *.cs file as shown below:

```
using System.Data;
```

Now look at my intellisense. It is heavily proliferated with whole lot of classes to choose from while typing in code editor. I'm not going to use whole bunch of classes at all:

[image]

So I would rather use an alias at the top of my *.cs file and get a clear intellisense view:

```
using SqlDataCon = System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
```

Now look at my intellisense view. It is super-clear and super-clean.

[image]

Comment: You're tightly coupling the code by doing this. Just create an interface. Aliasing should only be used to hide ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

One reason I know; It lets you use shorter names when you have name collisions from imported namespaces.
Example:

If you declared `using System.Windows.Forms;` and  `using System.Windows.Input;`  in the same file when you go to access `ModifierKeys` you might find that the name `ModifierKeys` is in both the `System.Windows.Forms.Control` and `System.Windows.Input` namespaces.
So by declaring `using Input = System.Windows.Input;` you can then get `System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys` via `Input.ModifierKeys`.

I'm not a C# buff but aliasing namespace seems like "best practise" to me. That way you know what you're getting and still don't have to type too much more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use them to modify a code very easily.

For example:

```
#if USE_DOUBLES
using BNumber = System.Double;
#else
using BNumber = System.Single;
#endif

public void BNumber DoStuff(BNumber n) {
    // ...
}
public void BNumber DoStuff2(BNumber n) {
    // ...
}
public void BNumber DoStuff3(BNumber n) {
    // ...
}
```

By the simple change in of the directive you can decide if your whole code works in `float` or `double`.

Comment: Anyone see this, never do this. In unit tests, it may be ok. In application code it should not be used.