# Using same alias for multiple namespaces

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, using

Is it possible to somehow use the same `using` alias for multiple namespaces, for which I know they don't have overlapping class names, in C#?
For example if I could do something like this:

```
using NSP = namespace1.namespace2;
using NSP = namespace1.namespace3;
```

`namespace2` and `namespace3` don't have classes with the same name, so there're no worries about ambiguous class names, and it would be more convenient for me to write:

```
NSP.Class1 obj1 = new NSP.Class1();
```

than

```
NSP.namespace2.Class1 obj1 = new NSP.namespace2.Class1();
```

in case I use

```
using NSP = namespace1;
```

Comment: Just my opinion... but I absolutely hate it when people do this in our code base... uuggghhh.

Answer (score 2):

```
using NSP = namespace1.namespace2;
using NSP = namespace1.namespace3;
```

You can't do that first of all. Compiler doesn't let you define same aliases for two different namespaces. That gives compiler time error.

> namespace2 and namespace3 don't have classes with the same name, so
>   there're no worries about ambiguous class names,

It doesn't matter they have same named classes or not, compiler doesn't let you do that.

- [C# namespace alias - what's the point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505262/c-sharp-namespace-alias-whats-the-point)
- [extern alias (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx)
- [C# Aliases](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11856/C-2-0-Aliases)

Comment: I know that this doesn't compile, I just stated the example to clarify what was on my mind. My question was if there's any way or a workaround for this issue.

Comment: @kobac I don't think so. If compiler tells you you shouldn't do this, you should not :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use same alias name again. you will get the following compiler error

> The using alias 'xxx' appeared previously in this namespace

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, even the two namespaces don't have classes with the same name.
You will get thsi error  :

The using alias 'NSP' appeared previously in this namespace.