# Identical class names across different namespaces - how to access class via immediate parent namespace?

Tags: c#, namespaces

Imagine I have the following namespace structure:

```
- components
--- x
----- [MyComponent]
----- [YourComponent]
--- y
----- [MyComponent]
----- [YourComponent]
```

`MyComponent` and `YourComponent` are classes within the `x` and `y` namespaces.

My understanding was that I would be able to access the desired class by `using components;` and accessing them via `x.MyComponent` and `y.MyComponent`. This however doesn't seem to be the case, and I have to use the longer namespace name: `components.x.MyComponent`.

Is there a solution that would allow me to use the next immediate namespace in the hierarchy (e.g. `x` or `y`) to distinguish between the classes, rather than a 'full' or 'longer' namespace name (e.g. `component.x` and `components.y`)?

PS: I'm aware of the issues around class name sharing

**Edit:** Apologies, I'd like to know if there's a solution that doesn't require using aliases (if possible) unless it provides a workaround that allows me to specify `x.MyComponent`

Comment: You could achieve it partially, e.g. use `using components.x;`, then short names would point to that namespace and if you'd want to get the other class, you'd need to use full name, as you use now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options here. You could:

A) Use an alias for the class:

```
using MyXComponent = components.x.MyComponent;
...
new MyXComponent();
```

B) Add using for one of these namespaces which contains the class (without alias):

```
using components.x;
...
new MyComponent(); // will create an x.MyComponent
```

C) Combine both approaches:

```
using x = components.x;  
using y = components.y;  
...
new x.MyComponent();
new y.MyComponent();
```

P.S.

The compiler needs to know which of the two classes you're looking for and if it finds two classes with the same name in namespaces included in `using` directives it throws a compile time error "xx is an ambiguous reference between this and that". Using of aliases allows us to help compiler to distinguish between the two.

Comment: Solution (C) suits my needs perfectly, although was hoping there'd be a workaround without aliases

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't have classes with the same names, however you can use alias directives C# 6

```
// Using alias directive for a classes
using MyComponentX = components.x.MyComponent;
using MyComponentY = components.y.MyComponent;
```

**Usage**

```
MyComponentX instance1 = new MyComponentX();
```

Or if they are similar enough for the same name, Maybe generics?

**Additional reading**

[using Directive (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive)

Answer (score 1):

We can use namespace aliasing to avoid long namespaces.

for example

```
using compX = components.x;
using compY = components.y;
```

Now we can distinguish same class present in different namespaces with the help of **namespace aliasing**

Like

```
  compX.MyComponent  //This will refer to MyComponent class from x namespcae
```

For more details: [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505262/c-sharp-namespace-alias-whats-the-point)