# Visual Studio 2017 c# export data to Excel

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2017

Am trying to export data from an array to an Excel worksheet.

Found a very good tutorial on how to do it right here:

http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-create-excel.htm

Have added a reference to Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object library v1.9

However when I attempt to type in "excel" am getting no properties or methods for Excel, which I guess indicates I am using the wrong keyword.

Anyone know what I should be doing.

```
private void btnExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Excel. <- ??????        
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you add a `using` statement to the top of the file? See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-excel-from-visual-c) for more information.

`using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`

Comment: had  "using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;"., made the change now working like a brought one, thanks mate.

Answer (score 2):

It's called [Namespace alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505262/c-sharp-namespace-alias-whats-the-point), You can achieve it in this way

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```