# 'Random' is an ambiguos reference between 'UnityEngine.Random' and 'System.Random' Error Unity 3D C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class Building : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum State
    {
        Nothing,
        Burnt,
        Cold
    };

    private void Start()
    {
        var max = Enum.GetValues(typeof(State)).Length;
        var value = (State)new Random().Next(0, max - 1);
        Console.WriteLine(value); 
    }
}
```

I did some research and any answer I found, was either too confusing and I didn't know how to implement it into my script or it required me to delete `Using System;` or `Using UnityEngine;`. How can I fix this issue?

Thanks! :D

PS. I probably didn't do enough research and it was right in front of me this whole time, so please excuse that.

Comment: You can either use a [namespace alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505262/c-sharp-namespace-alias-whats-the-point) or move the `using System`/`using UnityEngine` into your `Building` class - depending on what `Random` you want to use.

Comment: Simply put `using Random = UnityEngine.Random;` on top of your file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Random is an ambiguous reference in that case because both UnityEngine and System namespaces have a definition for Random.

You have to be more precise about which one you want to use:

```
var value = (State)new System.Random().Next(0, max - 1);
```

Or

```
var value = (State)new UnityEngine.Random().Next(0, max - 1);
```

**Edit:** As suggested by derHugo in the comment section you can define which definition you want to use. You can add this on top of the file:

```
 using Random = UnityEngine.Random;
```

Comment: I would rather go for `using Random = UnityEngine.Random;` on top of the file